# Обновить контент в div блоке на jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Здравствуйте друзья!
У меня на страничке имеется форма с данными, она используется в двух разных ситуациях, при добавлении данных и при редактировании, но при редактировании она немного изменяется, так вот если я нажимаю на кнопку "Редактировать" вношу изменения а потом нажимаю на кнопку "Добавить", то у меня отображается форма от предыдущего редактирования, как исправить данную ситуацию, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
//Modal for Add User
div.modal.fade(id='myModalAddUser')
    div.modal-dialog(id='modalDialog')
        div.modal-content
            div.modal-header
                button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-label='Close')
                    span(aria-hidden='true') &times;
                h4.modal-title.text-success Добавление пользователя!
            div.modal-body(id='modalBody')
                fieldset
                    legend Форма добавления нового пользователя
                    div.form-group.col-md-8
                        label.control-label.hidden(for='id') Id:
                        input.form-control.sr-only(name='id', id='id', type='text')
                    div.form-group.col-md-8
                        label.control-label(for='name') Введите имя:
                        input.form-control(name='name', id='name', type='text', placeholder='Имя', required='true')
                    div.form-group.col-md-8
                        label.control-label(for='login') Введите логин:
                        input.form-control(name='login', id='login', type='text', placeholder='Логин', required='true')
                    div.form-group.col-md-8
                        label.control-label(for='password') Введите пароль:
                        input.form-control(name='password', id='password', type='password', placeholder='Пароль', required='true')
                    div.form-group.col-md-8
                        label.control-label(for='confirm') Подтвердите пароль:
                        input.form-control(name='confirm', id='confirm', type='password', placeholder='Подтверждение', required='true')
                    div.form-group.col-md-8
                        label.control-label(for='email') Введите email:
                        input.form-control(name='email', id='email', type='email', placeholder='Email', required='true')
                    div.form-group.col-md-8
                        label.control-label(for='rules') Выберите права:
                        select.form-control(id='rules', name='rules')
                            -each item in rules
                                option(value=item.id) #{item.name}
            div.modal-footer
                button.btn.btn-danger(type='button', id='closeUser', data-dismiss='modal')
                    span.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove
                    | Закрыть
                button.btn.btn-primary(type='button', id='saveUser')
                    span.glyphicon.glyphicon-check
                    | Сохранить`    

`$('#new_user').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#myModalAddUser').modal('show');
        });`


`$('.actions>a.glyphicon-edit').each(function () {
        $(this).on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var attr        = this.getAttribute('href'),
                url         = attr.split('/');
            $.ajax({
                url     : '/admin/users/edit',
                method  : 'POST',
                data    : { id: url[4] },
                success : function (data) {
                    var user = data.user[0];
                    modalBody.find('.form-group').eq(4).addClass('hidden');
                    modalWindow.find('.modal-title').text('Редактирование пользователя!');
                    modalBody.find('legend').text('Форма редактирования пользователя');
                    $('#id').val(user.id);
                    $('#name').val(user.name);
                    $('#login').val(user.login);
                    $('#password').val(user.password);
                    $('#email').val(user.email);
                    var options = $('#rules').find('option');
                    options.each(function () {
                        if ($(this).val() == user.rule_id) {
                            this.selected = true;
                        }
                    });
                    modalWindow.modal('show');
                    $('#saveUser').on('click', function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url         : '/admin/users/save',
                            method      : 'POST',
                            data        : {
                                id      : $('#id').val(),
                                name    : $('#name').val(),
                                login   : $('#login').val(),
                                password: $('#password').val(),
                                email   : $('#email').val(),
                                rule_id : $('#rules').val()
                            },
                            success     : function (data) {
                                userTable.html(data);
                                modalWindow.modal('hide');
                                $('#myModalAddUser').refresh();
                            }
                        })
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: перед открытием просто очищай все поля на форме

Comment: @Grundy У меня некоторые поля просто скрыты, и даже если очистить поля, то недостающих то все равно не будет.

Comment: не понял, что значит _если очистить поля, то недостающих то все равно не будет_?